# Yii. Финча генератора чекбоксов

Tags: php, yii

Средствами YII генерирую список чекбоксов. Проблема в то, что последний чекбокс фактически работает как "выбрать всех" хотя не должен. Похоже, что это финча самого фреймворка. Как с эти бороться?

```
<?php
    foreach ($users as $key => $user)
    {
        print "<tr><td>";
        print $user->fullname . "</td><td>";
        print CHtml::activeHiddenField($Form, 'userId', array('value' => $user->id));
        if (in_array($user->id, $usersId))
        {
            print CHtml::activeCheckBox($form, "responsibility", array('checked' => TRUE));
        }
        else
        {
            print CHtml::activeCheckBox($form, "responsibility");
        }
        print "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм велосипед какой-то.

Не проще взять компонент и вывести нужные чекбоксы?

```
$form->checkBoxList($model, 'categories',users::model()->findAll());
```